# Can I reduce the number of solutions/topics in a summary plot graph?

Tags: r

[image]I want to plot a graphic about the prevalence of topics over time with a K=100. That's too much for the graph so I want just the 10 highest ranked topics. Like you see in the image. How can I limit these topics for a readable graph?

I created a stm and can plot all topics.

```
anzahl_topic <- 100
dfm2stm <- convert(fed_speeches.dfm.trim, to = "stm")
stm.modell <- stm(dfm2stm$documents, dfm2stm$vocab, K = anzahl_topics, data = dfm2stm$meta, init.type = "Spectral")
plot(stm.modell, type = "summary", text.cex = 0.5, main = "Proportion on the whole Corpus", xlab = "Estimation of Topic")
```

I get 100 topics in a graph ranked by the prevalence, but I just want the top 10 topics in this graph.
I think it could be limited with topics =  but I don't know the necessary command (for example: sample give only random topics).

Comment: Can you `dput` some of your data so we can reproduce your current plot?

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpfull to reproduce your issue. When I look at the stm() docs (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stm/versions/1.3.3/topics/stm), I can see that **K** is our amount of topics. You defined **K = anzahl_topics** and before that **anzahl_topics <- 100**. So I would expect to get 100 topics. Can you adjust your first line to **anzahl_topics <- 10**?

Comment: I get this K=100 after the searchK algorithm of the stm package. Therefor I think it suite my corpus well (corpus of 869 documents). But the visualization is the problem like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to plot a subset. Not sure the structure of your model object without a reproducible example, but it would be something like this:

```r
top10 <- subset(stm.model1, topics = 10)
plot(top10, type = "summary", text.cex = 0.5, main = "Proportion on the whole Corpus", xlab = "Estimation of Topic")
```

Comment: Please look at the picture and you will see the problem. If I would do a subset I might rank this as well. I thought I could just limit the output of the topics with a single command in the plot function.